# Class cast exception in clojure

Tags: exception, clojure, control-flow

Getting `clojure.core$count cannot be cast to java.lang.Number` error for defined variable `count`

```
(defroutes jobs-routes
      (context "/jobs" []
        (POST "/jobValidation" [name status req]  (insert-job jobName jobStatus req)))
```

In this method I've define a variable `count` to store the value of total count from the query

```
(defn insert-job [jobName jobStatus req]
   (let [count (db/insert-job {:job-name name :status status})])
    (when (> count 0) (println (format "true" )))
    (insert-job req) ; 
)
```

**Query: db/insert-job**

```
-- :name insert-jobWithValidation :? :*
SELECT count(*)  FROM job_history WHERE job_name = :job-name and status = :status
```

**Problem**
I want to check that whether If I'm getting out value greater than 0 so I can print something any if count is any positive value then I can perform something new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is probably because of your `hugsql` query header:

`:? :*` - returns the rowset, which is not a number.
maybe `:? :1` would be more suitable here. Anyway, the query doesn't return a `count(*)`, it rather returns a hash-map (in case of :1) or a list of one hashmap (in case of :*), you would still need to retrieve the value from there.

Something like that (untested):

```
-- :name insert-jobWithValidation :? :1
SELECT count(*) as amount  FROM job_history WHERE job_name = :job-name and status = :status
```

```
(defn insert-job [name status req]
  (let [res (db/insert-job {:job-name name :status status})]
    (when (-> res :amount pos?) 
      (println true))
    (insert-job req)))
```

*UPD*: omg, let with no body, indeed, @Martin Půda, thanks )

i would say, what you want is something like that:

```
-- :name count-jobs-by-name-and-status :? :1
SELECT count(*) as amount  FROM job_history WHERE job_name = :job-name and status = :status
```

```
(defn insert-job-if-not-exists [name status req]
  (if (->> {:job-name name :status status}
           db/count-jobs-by-name-and-status
           :amount
           pos?)
    (println "job already exists")
    (insert-job req)))
```

Comment: getting *java.lang.NullPointerException* at pos?

Comment: could you please try to log what you got in `res`? i bet that would clarify the whole thing

Comment: this is stored in res :  {:count 1}

Comment: this is exact count for which I want the job with particular name & status

Comment: this is weird. have you updated your sql with alias to 'amount' as shown above?

Comment: I've missed it, thanks

Comment: Can you tell how to send a conflict response with Id (jobId) in place of print true?

Comment: it depends on your app structure. the simplest here would be `(ring.util.http-response/conflict! "job already exists")`. this would throw an exception up. Though i consider it dirty to throw http status aware exception from the service layer.

Comment: Can I send conflict response with a jobId for the job already exists, I know we have to bind (let) to returning response ?

Comment: Can you just show how can I add id to the body param of conflict

Answer (score 3):

Your `let` block has no body, you're closing it right after definitions vector:

`(let [count (db/insert-job {:job-name name :status status})])`

Note that you are shadowing core function `count` here.

So when you call this line:
`(when (> count 0) (println (format "true" )))`, the value of `count` is [`count`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/count) function:

```
count
=> #object[clojure.core$count 0x69c6a700 "clojure.core$count@69c6a700"]
(> count 0)
Execution error (ClassCastException)
class clojure.core$count cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number
```

There are some other errors and style inaccuracies:

- the names of your variables don't match (`jobName jobStatus` vs `name status`)
- you're calling `(insert-job req)` with only one argument, but this function has three
- `(> ... 0)` is [`pos?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pos_q)
- `(format "true")` is just `"true"`

Possible fix (maybe you will still have to modify it somehow):

```
(defn insert-job [job-name job-status req]
  (let [my-count (db/insert-job {:job-name job-name :status job-status})]
    (if (pos? my-count)
      (println "true")
      (insert-job job-name job-status req))))
```

Comment: tried your solution but getting * clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Number* at pos?