# How can I send a Conflict response with an Id in clojure

Tags: validation, clojure, response

I've defined a method where I'm simply checking where a job exists with a specific name and status, in case if job exists I want to send a conflict response but with an id

```
(defn insert-job [name status req]
      (if (->> {:job-name name :status status}
               db/insert-job
               :amount
               pos? )
        (conflict)  ; here I want to send a response as conflicts with a particular id as Long
        (insert-job req)))
```

As in the below method I am able to produce a `created` response as Long

```
(defn insert-job [req]
  (let [[errors job] (v/validate-job (:body req))]
    (if errors
      (unprocessable-entity {:errors errors})
      (let [id (db/insert-job job)]
        (created (format "/jobs/%d" id) {:id id})))))
```

Comment: Follow-up of [Class cast exception in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75285679/class-cast-exception-in-clojure). Do you have a link to the repository with this code, or could you at least explain, what `v/validate-job`, `unprocessable-entity`, `created`, `db/insert-job` functions do? We had to guess a lot the last time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. this would be as easy as

1. update your query to find the job id if exists
2. update your code to actually throw it.

in your hugsql queries file:

```
-- :name find-job-id :? :1
select id from job_history 
where name = :name and status = :status 
limit 1;
```

in your repo:

```
(defn insert-job [name status rec]
  (if-let [id (some->> {:name name :status status}
                       (find-job-id db-spec)
                       :id)]
    (ring.util.http-response/conflict! 
      {:message "record already exists"
       :id id})

    ;; here do whatever you need for actual insertion
    ))
```

but ok. i would heavily advice you to read something on your chosen language and libraries.